# BlackBerry code signing warning

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I use following line of code in my blackberry java application (6.0)

```
private static final int HPADDING = Display.getWidth() <= 320 ? 6 : 8;
```

but Eclipse gives me a warning saying That :

```
Signing Required: RIM Runtime API (0x52525400): Protected Class     
net.rim.device.api.system.Display
```

The application installed on the device but it doesn't run. So I want to know that Is there any method to do this without signing the application. I'm very much new to blackberry please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: is there any problem in signing your app ?. signing is for security.

Comment: This element is only accessible by signed applications. If you intend to use this element, please visit http://www.blackberry.com/go/codesigning to obtain a set of code signing keys. Code signing is only required for applications running on BlackBerry smartphones; development on BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators can occur without code signing.

Comment: I tried to signing codes. After filling the necessary form received three keys but I have no that much experience so code signing didn't work. Is there any alternative method to do so. 

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Unfortunatly there are no ways other than code signing. Could you please post what problems are you facing while signing code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code contains a reference to Signed API then you have to sign your application before installing it on actual device. Unsigned application that uses Signed API can run on a simulator but won't launch on an actual device.

Apply for signing keys here: http://www.blackberry.com/go/codesigning

You will receive an email with attached signing keys. Follow the instructions in the received email to install these keys and use them to sign your application.